# new item on top of list in list view from sqlite database in android

Tags: android

How to display new item on top in list view from sqlite database in android

the code is as follows:

my displayData() method :

```
private void displayData()
                {
        dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);
        userId.clear();
        Name.clear();
        Description.clear();
                Assignto.clear();
                Duration.clear();
                Priority.clear();
                Category.clear();
                Kudos.clear();
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst())
                  {
            do {
                userId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.KEY_ID)));
                Name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.Name)));
                Description.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.Description)));
                                Assignto.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.Assignto)));
                                Duration.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.Duration)));
                                Priority.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.Priority)));
                                Category.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.Category)));
                                Kudos.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.Kudos)));                                       }
                     while (mCursor.moveToNext());
          }
CustomList adapter = new CustomList(tasklist.this,userId,Name,Description,Assignto,Duration,Priority,Category,Kudos,imageId);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        mCursor.close();
            }`
```

My Custom list adapter class:

```
 public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent)
          {
           Holder mHolder;
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        if (child == null)
            {
                    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null);
                    mHolder = new Holder();
                    mHolder.imageId=(ImageView) child.findViewById(R.id.img);
                    mHolder.txt_Name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_Name);
                    mHolder.txt_Description = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_Description);
                    mHolder.txt_Assignto = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_Assignto);
                    child.setTag(mHolder);
            }
           else {
                   mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
                }

            mHolder.imageId.setImageResource(imageId[pos]);
            mHolder.txt_Name.setText(Name.get(pos));
            mHolder.txt_Description.setText(Description.get(pos));
            mHolder.txt_Assignto.setText(Assignto.get(pos));
            return child;
      }
    public class Holder
     {

            ImageView imageId;
            TextView txt_Name;
            TextView txt_Description;
            TextView txt_Assignto;
    }
```

i tried "desc" in query but not working and showing error.

Comment: What query string are you using (with desc clause) that give an error? Maybe is the query that is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `moveToLast()` method , which will start displaying your data from last to first

```
if(cursor.moveToLast()){
     do{
         //your operations here
     }while(cursor.moveToPrevious());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have column such as row_ID is Integer primary key(using autoincrease or you must increase value) in database?
If you have this column, try desc.

```
Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ DbHelper.TABLE_NAME + " order by userId DESC;", null);
```

columnName is primary key column.
Then, result is data witch is input data in sorted.

If your database doesn't have integer primary key value such as row_id, I think you must create this field for get select one row or more row data.

Comment: yeah i m using primary id as userId which is auto increment

Comment: then, you can use userId for sorting data. I edit my answer using userId.

Comment: dude i got answer by below post by kunu.. still ur post was very useful thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

You Should get the data in reverse order through id column of the database .  here example of Cursor query .you can get it through rawquery also.

```
 db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(helper.Table_name,null,null,null,null,null,helper._id + " DESC ");

             // THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
String[] columns = new String[] {helper.KeyName, helper.KeyVlue };
            // THE XML DEFINED VIEWS WHICH THE DATA WILL BE BOUND TO
 int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name, R.id.score };

            // CREATE THE ADAPTER USING THE CURSOR POINTING TO THE DESIRED DATA AS WELL AS THE LAYOUT INFORMATION
 MyCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.simpl_list_item,cursor,columns,to,0);

            // SET THIS ADAPTER AS YOUR LISTACTIVITY'S ADAPTER   
 list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```